# How do you get the set of available CPUs in a Linux kernel module?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, cpu

I would like to start one kernel thread per CPU with kthread_create()/kthread_bind(). However, I can't for the life of me figure out how to query the number of available CPUs. I did find the CPU_SET man page but that didn't help either.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See following link, [cpuinfo.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/proc/cpuinfo.c), [proc.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/kernel/cpu/proc.c), may be help you. And 
at line 143, you can use two functions for traversing cpus, cpumask_first, cpumask_next. I think, by try and error, you can find the solutions.

Comment: Thanks Ocean. With your help I found linux/cpumask.h where int nr_cpu_ids is defined which has exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @user1046602, please, accept the answer for making this question is answered and closed :)

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can use num_online_cpus() to get the number of available cpus.  This may be different from things like nr_cpu_ids if the system was booted using a maxcpus setting that is not the same as the number of cpus in the system.

Answer (score 0):

You can use x86info. It's not per default installed (sudo apt-get install x86info (ubuntu))

```
x86info | grep Found
Found 2 CPUs
```

another way is:

```
grep processor /proc/cpuinfo | wc -l
2
```

Is that you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a system that is Fedora Linux / RHEL / CentOS v6+ / Debian Linux v6+ you can use [`lscpu`](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-display-cpu-information-number-of-cpus-and-their-speed/):

```
michael@test:~$ lscpu
Architecture:          i686
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    2
Socket(s):             1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 37
Stepping:              5
CPU MHz:               1199.000
BogoMIPS:              5319.88
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              3072K
```

Particularly you might be interested in the `-p` option which gives you parseable output:

```
michael@test:~$ lscpu -p
# The following is the parsable format, which can be fed to other
# programs. Each different item in every column has an unique ID
# starting from zero.
# CPU,Core,Socket,Node,,L1d,L1i,L2,L3
0,0,0,,,0,0,0,0
1,0,0,,,0,0,0,0
2,1,0,,,1,1,1,0
3,1,0,,,1,1,1,0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ nproc --all
4
```

--all  print the number of installed processors